# Not able to fetch data while running react js app on ip(192.168.XX.XXX) address

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, express

I am trying to fetch backend data in react app using fetch api . Its working when I am running react app on localhost but if I change address localhost to IP , Its not working its showing `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch` .

Here is my code

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/post/allposts')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log('data', json);
      });
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606969/unhandled-rejection-typeerror-failed-to-fetch

Comment: @James Checked . Its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Add cors to backend and pass the url in origin array from which you are accessing.

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://your-ip-address:port/']
}));
```

Comment: still not working .